# Adding items from pairs in list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I zip pairs in a list-of-lists?

```
 A=[[ 1,2 ],[ 3  ,  4]]
 B=[[ 4,5 ],[ 8  ,  9]]
 ->(1,4),(2,5),(3,8),(4,9)
```

I've tried something like `zip(*A,*B)` but I'm getting `SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression`.

In the end what I'm trying to do is add them:

```
 A=[[ 1,2 ],[ 3  ,  4]]
 B=[[ 4,5 ],[ 8  ,  9]]
  =[[ 5,7 ],[ 11 , 13]]
```

(also doesn't work):

```
add= [i+j for i,j in zip(*A,*B)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `zip` both `A` and `B` and then `zip` the lists given by the previous `zip`, like this

```
result = []
for items in zip(A, B):
    for data in zip(*items):
        result.append(data)
```

The same can be written succinctly as a List Comprehension, like this

```
>>> [data for items in zip(A, B) for data in zip(*items)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 8), (4, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`numpy`](http://numpy.org/):

```
>>> A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> B = [[4, 5], [8, 9]]
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array(A) + numpy.array(B)
array([[ 5,  7],
       [11, 13]])

>>> list(map(list, _))
[[5, 7], [11, 13]]
```